# Ajax request with content type set to application/json interpreted by Rails as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, cross-domain, cors

I have 2 domains: `language.com` and `bonjour.language.com`.

I want to make a `POST` request from `bonjour.language.com` to the root domain.

I'm using Backbone:

```
model.save(null,
  xhrFields:
    withCredentials: true
)
```

I see the preflight request, then the actual request.

The request

- Content-Type:application/json
- Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
- the cookie is passed (Cookie: mp_3b2796f7...)
- Host:language.com
- Origin: bonjour.language.com

When a request is cross domain, the csrf token is obviously not passed, so I disabled the verification on the server for the create action.

In the controller, when I log `request.format`, I get `text/html`. **Any ideas why?**
(the response is a 406 Unacceptable, since I don't have a block handling the html format).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, and it's pretty ironic.

Here's what ended up working:

```
model.save(null,
  xhrFields:
    withCredentials: true
  crossDomain: false
)
```

`crossDomain: false` for a cross domain request? Weird right?

This tricks jQuery into sending the X-Requested-with header set to XMLHttpRequest.

It is not set by default for cross domain requests.

But it is necessary for Rails to know that the request is an XMLHttpRequest though, and so that it can use the content type to set the request format!

Another approach, lengthier but maybe more explicit would be to set the header yourself:

```
model.save(null,
  xhrFields:
    withCredentials: true
  beforeSend: (request) ->
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest')
)
```